# Nginx Location Directive fail

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm trying this `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        }

        location /pages/ {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/static/;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `/usr/share/nginx/html/static/pages/` there is a file `page1.html`.

But, when I do `GET /pages/page1.html`, I receive this error: `[error] 31#31: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/pages/page1.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /pages/page1.html HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"`.

Nginx is a dockerized container with port 8080 mapped to 80.

Why doesn't Nginx concatenate `/static/` in the path?

Comment: Recommendation to read up on the alias directive: http://nginx.org/r/alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [recommendation](http://nginx.org/r/alias) made by @palindromeotter33, this is the answer:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        }

        location /pages/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static/pages/;
        }
    }
}
```